# Internet Explorer 11 transition translateY acting strange

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to transition an element from top to bottom, (0 to 100vh). Internet explorer 11 is doing weird things, when transitioning transform property. It is going up when it should go down and not respecting the duration.

[**JSFIDDLE1**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnau2cws/)

[**JSFIDDLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnau2cws/1)

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
    transition:transform 5s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 5s;
}

div:hover{
    transform:translateY(100vh);
    -ms-transform:translateY(100vh);
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: This is likely related to the issue(s) [I tweeted about some time ago](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/491671062807973888). I have opened up an issue regarding this internally and will add this Question to the list of examples where people have been bitten by this issue.

Comment: You seem to know quite much about it, do you know if it is ie11 only?

Comment: I work on the IE team. The test I created (in the above linked tweet) also repros in Internet Explorer 10. We haven't immediately addressed it only because there were far more pressing matters that we wanted to resolve sooner. But, [today we shipped over 2,000 interop fixes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-interoperability.aspx), so we have a lot of momentum.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. So its a bug, is there any way to bypass it?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but I ran into this same issue today. I'm building a kind of slideshow that uses CSS transitions to animate slides in and out. Most browsers handle `transform: translateX(-100vw)` and `transform: translateY(-100vh)` to move slides left and up respectively, but IE has trouble calculating the correct start/end positions and gets confused on the timing just like @Alvaro mentioned.

The solution is to use absolute units (e.g., pixels) rather than relative. But, given the wide range of screen sizes I need to support, I can't use a single value.

My work around was to use a series of `@media` queries to define a set of translation rules that will always ensure the slide moves off screen, but doesn't go too far. For example:

```
/* Slide left */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .slide.left {
    transform: translateX(-480px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .slide.left {
    transform: translateX(-960px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
  .slide.left {
    transform: translateX(-1920px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1921px) and (max-width: 3840px) {
  .slide.left {
    transform: translateX(-3840px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 3841px) {
  .slide.left {
    transform: translateX(-7680px);
  }
}

/* Slide up */
@media (max-height: 480px) {
  .slide.up {
    transforom: translateX(-480px);
  }
}
/* Etc. */
```

These queries would support up to 8K resolution, albeit with significantly less granularity at higher resolutions. You'll want to adjust them based on your expected usage.

Comment: Is this really the only solution?

Comment: No offense taken. ;)

Comment: I am not trying to be insulting but it seems like IE 11 (the latest version of IE) should have this fixed by now (over a year late) or someone should have found a real solution by now and not using tons of CSS queries. So I take that back, I am trying to be insulting to Microsoft, not you.

Comment: For the record, this seems to be an issue with all relative units, not just viewport units. I was using a translateY in ems and getting this issue. Switching to px fixed it. Thanks!